# Pandas dataframe apply calculations to selected rows

Tags: python, pandas, median

I am trying to calculate outliers in a dataset using Median Absolute Deviation. My dataset is 3 columns, 2000 rows in the following format:

```
Km      Price   id
139000  8500    2010 holden cruze cdx jg auto
173000  8500    2010 holden cruze cdx jg auto
95000   8800    2008 honda civic vti-l auto
141000  8800    2010 holden cruze cdx jg auto
169078  8880    1999 mazda mx-5 manual
```

How can I do array calculations like the following below. I want each row to have a 'median' value, which should be the median of all rows with the same id.

```
model = '2010 holden cruze cdx jg auto'
data[data['id']==model]['median'] = data[data['id']==model]['Price'].median()
```

The below statement provides the right median for each model, I just dont know how to quickly apply it to every row in the 'median' column.

```
median = data[data['id']==model]['Price'].median()
```

Or, alternatively, is my approach to Median Absolute Deviation wrong - is there a quicker/easier way to do it with pandas/numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) which returns a series the same length as the dataframe:

```
df['median'] = df.groupby('id').Price.transform('median')

>>> df
       Km  Price                             id  median
0  139000   8500  2010-holden-cruze-cdx-jg-auto    8500
1  173000   8500  2010-holden-cruze-cdx-jg-auto    8500
2   95000   8800    2008-honda-civic-vti-l-auto    8800
3  141000   8800  2010-holden-cruze-cdx-jg-auto    8500
4  169078   8880         1999-mazda-mx-5-manual    8880
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functions [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
data['median'] = data['id'].map(data.groupby('id')['Price'].median())
print data
```

Output:

```
       Km  Price                             id  median
0  139000   8500  2010-holden-cruze-cdx-jg-auto    8500
1  173000   8500  2010-holden-cruze-cdx-jg-auto    8500
2   95000   8800    2008-honda-civic-vti-l-auto    8800
3  141000   8800  2010-holden-cruze-cdx-jg-auto    8500
4  169078   8880         1999-mazda-mx-5-manual    8880
```